# c# format line to column

Tags: c#, formatting

I am formatting all text lines in to columns. The problem is , I don't know how to make that every line wich I split to words would start from first line in text and that all columns would be separated by one space. Appreciate any help. My code so far:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fvr))
{

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fv, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        var words = line.Split(skyrikliai2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            writer.WriteLine(words[i]);
        writer.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

the outcome of this would be(without symbol) :

- word
- word
- word
- word

and what I need is that line would be splited in words and every word of that line would be writen in new line and all next lines would be written in same way(by that I mean format all that in columns) , if it's easier to imagine as a matrix. Like so :

- word   word word
- word word word
- word word word
- word word word

Edit3. That's how I want the output to look :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CF5S.jpg)

Comment: Could you, please, provide an *example* of the initial data and the *desired outcome*?

Comment: edited my question ;)

Comment: What if we have *different* words? E.g. `a1 a2 \r\n b1 \r\n c1 c2 c3`?

Comment: yea, it was just my example, i though that maybe with same sentence it would be easier to understand , but yeah all lines are different in my text all words are different

Comment: my text looks like this : 
Būtų šaunu, jei daugiau lukas žmonių skaitytų deze mano knygas.
Bet reikia turėti kantrybės.
Dažniau duoti interviu, rengti skaitymo vakarus. 
Pirmąjį romaną išleidau pats, nes leidyklos knygą atmetė. 
Taigi lukas išleidau kitą knygą, strategiškai apgalvojęs. 
Skaitytojams lukas ta deze būtų aktuali. 
Argumentuodamos, kad deze vardas nežinomas lukas ir deze neturiu savo skaitytojų.
Lietuviams, deze pat koledžo Čikagoje studentams.

Comment: I still didn't follow you: the exact text doesn't matter, I can't catch the final format. Do you want just to put *each* word on a *new* line? One word per line?

Comment: mate, added image , I hope now you can help me with that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, finally… You want to *pivot* lines, e.g. for the test input

```
a1, a2, a3
b1
c1; c2
```

the expected output should be

```
a1 b1 c1
a2    c2 
a3
```

You can implement a `Pivot` as follows

```
private static List<List<String>> Pivot(String[][] source) {
  var numRows = source.Max(a => a.Length);
  var numCols = source[0].Length;

  var result = new List<List<String>>(numRows);

  for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
    List<String> line = Enumerable.Repeat("", numCols).ToList();

    result.Add(line);

    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col)
      if (source[col].Length > row)
        line[col] = source[col][row];
  }

  return result;
}
```

And use [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) to obtain

```
var result = Pivot(File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1257))
  .Select(line => line.Split(skyrikliai2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
  .ToArray());

File.WriteAllLines(
  @"C:\OtherFile.txt", 
  result
     .line => string.Join("\t", line),
  Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
```

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko, sry , but it just does not work in my case , i can't use this option in foreach loop or should I use for ?

Comment: @Oscar: same idea with `foreach` loop: `Join` the words instead of *inmost* `foreach`

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for your effort, but that's the problem I am keep getting. All words from all lines they are in same column. I need that every lines words would be in separated columns

Comment: @Oscar: that's high time you should provide an *example* (in the question's body) of the *initial* data and and the *desired outcome*.

Comment: @Oscar: next time, please, start with *example*!

Answer (score 0):

I think u want to write every word in a single line.
for this format using **Environment.NewLine** instead of **'\n'**

Answer (score 0):

I'd use string.Join, you could possibly use LINQ aggregate too.

```
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fvr))
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fv,Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            var words = line.Split(skyrikliai2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var outputLine = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words);

            writer.WriteLine(outputLine);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it still prints out all words in one column, and I need to print out every line in new column and separated by space,  and I really appreciate your effort

Comment: Maybe you want to pivot?

Comment: By pivot I mean create a newline for each word?  Word1.  Word2.  Word3.

Comment: if with pivot I could write all line words in separated columns, then probably :D